# unzipping piping error on linux system

Tags: linux, pipe, wget, zip

I am trying to extract windows 10 and install it on linodes platform and my command is as follows:

```
wget -O- --no-check-certificate https://www.dropbox.com/s/e9vh4ahwcogi4xo/Win10_21H2_English_x64.zip?dl=0 | unzip | dd of=/dev/sda
```

My command is failing and I am not sure why?

I have tried:

```
wget -O- --no-check-certificate https://www.dropbox.com/s/e9vh4ahwcogi4xo/Win10_21H2_English_x64.zip?dl=0 | unzip-stdin /dev/sda | dd of=/dev/sda
```

I am getting a piping error. I am new to this and I would appreciate if someone could help me fix this or point me to the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: It's unclear what the error that you see says.

Comment: Is your .zip file an image backup of a previously-**installed** windows system? If so, what you're trying to do is possible (although I'd be inclined to use [clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) to do the backup and restore).   If it's just a Windows installer CD image, there's no way this will work - you need to boot that CD and follow the usual install procedure (and that would be off-topic for this site).   Once you have a working windows system you can make a disk image backup of it, and restore it.

Comment: BTW, there are ways to automate the installation of windows onto brand new machines, but that's also off-topic here.  Try https://superuser.com/ or microsoft support (although microsoft's own methods are fairly complicated, require a moderate investment in time & hardware to set up, and are meant for medium to large businesses with site licenses)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `unzip | dd of=/dev/sda` with `gunzip -c > /dev/sda` to get the functionality you're looking for. This will work as long as the zipfile contains a single file, such as an ISO image or a raw disk image.

As a test to confirm, even though `man gunzip` documents the functionality,

```
$ sha1sum testfile
018bde45704389c6de09fe44567e37821cc8c7f1  testfile
$ zip testfile.zip testfile
  adding: testfile (deflated 61%)
$ zcat testfile.zip | sha1sum
018bde45704389c6de09fe44567e37821cc8c7f1  -
```

Checksums are the same, leading me to suspect that your zip file isn't really in zip format.

Comment: my file is a zip file and I get an error: not in gzip format @doneal24

Comment: @Kanito `gunzip` is able to handle zip-formatted archives that contain a single image. I assumed this was the case since you're writing an image to a raw disk device. Since your link is not valid, I cannot check to see that is actually is in zip format. I suggest that you download to a disk file and check with unzip to confirm that it is what you expect.